# cannot reshape array of size 64 into shape (28,28)

Tags: python-3.x, image, machine-learning, reshape, mnist

Not able to reshape the image in mnist dataset using sklean
This is the starting portion of my code just load the data

```
some_digit  =   X[880] 
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,   28)
```

ERROR PART

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4d618bdb57bc> in <module>
      1 some_digit = X[880]
----> 2 some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,28)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 64 into shape (28,28)
```

Comment: well, 28 * 28 != 64, so you obviously cannot reshape them that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only reshape it into a 8, 8 array. 8x8=64

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
some_digit  =   X[880] 
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(8,   8)
```